# View Window's pending changes?

Tags: windows

I was closing open windows and about to turn my computer off, when I noticed a windows saying that I needed to restart to save the changes, and giving me the option to restart now or later.

The problem is, I'm nearly positive I didn't make any changes. Is there a way for me to figure out what's going to change?

Comment: Do you have automatic updates enabled on your PC?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey, No, I have it set to check but not to update automatically. I had updated to MS Word 2010 yesterday, which had made the updates automatic, so I had changed it back. All this was yesterday though, and I've restarted at least three times since.

Comment: Those messages sometimes come up after a driver install, did you  connect some USB or similar device recently?

Comment: @Bob, Nothing new. My printer is normally plugged in, but was unplugged after I cleaned my computer recently. I did plug it back in today, but I've never before received that message upon doing it.

Comment: Scan for malware just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might happen that you have turned-on automatic updates to download & install updates anytime when there are new updates available, after doing that the computer will prompt you to save all your work and restart your pc or restart later.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it's not that because otherwise there would be the little alert symbol over the shutdown button on the start menu.